# What did China do to increase the productivity of state-owned enterprises?

Tags: china, economy

> In recent years, however, Beijing is turning its back on the very
> policy reforms that helped propel it to greater economic growth.
> Maoist socialism is on the rise under the leadership of Xi Jinping and
> the role of SOEs in the economy has increased. As a result, dynamism
> in China is waning.
>
> As the IMF recently noted in its Article IV report on China’s economy
> in 2022, “SOEs are being tasked to make advances in strategically
> important sectors and technologies affected by growing geoeconomic
> fragmentation, further burdening them with responsibilities.” But
> these “strategic” decisions have costs.
>
> Indeed, it is estimated that China’s SOEs are about 20 percent less
> productive than private firms operating in the same sector and “the
> decline in business dynamism is particularly pronounced in sectors and
> regions with large SOE presence.”

https://www.cato.org/blog/new-research-highlights-how-chinese-soe-reform-helped-unleash-entrepreneurship-late-1990s

What did China do to increase the productivity of state-owned enterprises? According to the CATO institute, Chinese state-owned enterprises are 30 percent less productive than Chinese private firms operating in the same sector. I was wondering if there were any policy implemented in order to address this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a definition of exactly what they mean by "productivity" and "dynamism". If "productivity" means profitability in a conventional way, then it follows that a SOE performing functions for the state will yield less private profit for capital invested, since some resource is diverted into fulfilling those additional functions whose return does not accrue directly to the organisations performing them. Such "unproductivity" is not necessarily harmful, if the additional functions are useful for the Chinese economy and society.